# load balance between different tensorflow serving using nginx

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, tensorflow-serving

Is it possible to use nginx to load balance between mulitple tensorflow serving servers. I know tensorflow serving uses gRPC which uses http/2. I tried to use nginx out of the box but it didn't work. I keep getting an error `Trying to connect an http1.x server`. If it can't be done using nginx, what other load balance I can use? I dont want to use kubernetes as mentioned in tensorflow tutorial.

Comment: It is possible to use haproxy to forward the protocol as it to your gRPC server but no interception. It is not possible in Nginx to proxy pass directly to a HTTP/2 backend. What you need is a middleware proxy in between the two. See this article https://nghttp2.org/blog/2015/03/24/proxying-grpc-with-nghttpx/

Comment: I think I will give haproxy a try and give up on nginx. Thanks.

Comment: @TarunLalwani Do you I need to setup ssl certification or is it optional? will it work without SSL certification. Moreover, what do you mean by "interception"?

Answer (score 0):

what's the version of nginx you are using？That is supposed to higher than 1.13.10